# Videos only play when the window is resized to the smallest setting

Tags: video

Hard to describe my issue in one sentence.

Basically any video I play off my HDD (so either using the video player that comes with Ubuntu 13.04 or VLC) will only show the frames if the video player window size is small.  After a certain point of resizing the player, the video just disappears (though it's still playing audio and will come back if I resize to the small window again).

I realize my hardware is antiquated, but I am able to play movies in full screen on XBMC (although occasionally my computer freezes and crashes.)  I do disable unity when using XBMC though, perhaps this is the issue I'm facing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few things you can do to optimize your system that might solve this bizarre issue.

First, check that you have correct drivers for your GPU, if you even have one.  If you're just running integrated graphics, move on to the next step...

If your system is legacy you can try running a more lightweight desktop environment.  Unity is not a good GUI for old hardware.  I suggest the lubuntu, xubuntu, or kubuntu desktops.

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge ubuntu-desktop
```

This will uninstall unity and x. --purge line will remove the old files, to avoid conflict and optimize hard disk usage.  Next, pick which desktop environment to replace it with.

xubuntu - This is probably what you should try first.  Another lightweight Gnome desktop, but with significantly more features than lubuntu.  Works well on old hardware.

```
sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop
```

lubuntu - Extremely lightweight desktop environment running Gnome.  Works best on PC's with less than 1gb of ram.

```
sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop
```

kubuntu - This is an alternate suggestion because it's a very unique flavor of Ubuntu.  This desktop environment is based off of the Plasma GUI, a powerful feature rich GUI thats light on appearance and similar to Windows in style.

```
sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop
```

Kubuntu desktop environment really shines when you use the Koffice office suite with it.  Features like drag and drop to bring spreadsheets and graphs and images into word documents that are unavailable on any other desktop environment make it very unique.  Koffice is slightly less compatible with MSOffice formats than libre office though.

Hope this helps.  I can't think of anything else to help you, your problem definitely sounds like a lack of VRAM is causing it.  Also, XBMC runs pretty choppy even on my computer, and I have a next gen system, so you should avoid that software if possible.

Comment: I'll probably end up installing just XMBC and using it as a media player, finally got my laptop up and running.

Thanks for the tips though